# jquery form plugin to edit an entire form in place

Tags: forms, jquery-plugins

I've been searching a bit for a jquery plugin that could help me to edit an entire form in place without having to write markup for both the form and displaying the data. Where you can just click "edit" and then the form fields would appear instead of the text, and then save and the form fields would turn into text again.

Does anyone know of one?

Comment: There's no real need for a plugin. In fact, I believe a custom-made solution is more suitable. Post an example of markup.

Comment: @Jakob: I have a custom jQuery plugin I wrote just for this. I can .zip it across to ur mail id if you want to give it a try.

Comment: @conqenator - I'd very much like that, how can I post my email without being spammed?

Comment: @Jakob: post it here now. and delete your comment once i've acknowledged.  ;)

Comment: @Jakob: mailed it you. hope it helps. :)

Comment: @conqenator - thank you, very nice plugin and pretty simple to adjust, thx a bunch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the plugin in its crudest form:

```
  (function( $ ){
    var YesNo = new Array();
        YesNo["true"] = "Yes";
        YesNo["false"] = "No";
    $.fn.inline = function() {
            this.each(function(){
            if ($(this).is('table')) {
                $(this).find('input, select, textarea').not('[type=button],[type=submit]').each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr("type")=="checkbox"){
                        $(this).parent().append("<span class=\"editable\">"+YesNo[$(this).attr('checked')]+"</span>");
                        $(this).hide();
                        //$(this).append("<span>"+$(this).val()+"</span>");
                        $(this).bind('blur',function(){
                            var t = YesNo[$(this).attr('checked')];
                            $(this).hide().next().show().text(t);
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).parent().append("<span class=\"editable\">"+$(this).val()+"</span>");
                        $(this).hide();
                        //$(this).append("<span>"+$(this).val()+"</span>");
                        $(this).bind('blur',function(){
                            var t = $(this).val();
                            $(this).hide().next().show().text(t);
                        });
                    }
                });
                $(this).find('td').live('dblclick', function(){
                        $(this).children('.editable').hide().prev().show().focus();
                });
            }    
        });
      };
    })( jQuery );
```

Call to plugin:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {
        $('#dataform').inline();
    });
 </script>
```

And the supporting example markup:

```
<table id="dataform">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="Robin" /> </td>

            <td class="label">Last Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="Maben" /> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="label">City</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="Bangalore" /> </td>

            <td class="label">Country</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="styleLabel">Status</td>
            <td class="styleControl">
                <select id="Select1" class="styleDrop">
                    <option>Active</option>
                    <option>Inavtive</option>
                    <option>Pending</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td><td><textarea>Hello World</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type = "button" value="Click" />
                <input type = "submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```